# django: template show timezone also for the datetime

Tags: django

I am sending the following datetime timezone aware object to django template

```
current_time = timezone.now()
```

In my template i am showing it using

```
{{ current_time }}
```

it displays as:

```
Feb. 10, 2021, 3:25 a.m
```

I want it to display as

```
Feb. 10, 2021, 3:25 a.m UTC
```

I dont see which timezone the time is. So i want to be more clear by adding the timezone.

how can i do this in django template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
{{ current_time |date:"b d Y f a T" }}
```

- b:Month, textual, 3 letters, lowercase.  'jan'
- d:Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros. '01' to '31' Y:Year,
  4 digits.    '1999'
- f:Time, in 12-hour hours and minutes, with minutes left off if
  they’re zero. Proprietary extension.
- a:'a.m.' or 'p.m.' (Note that this is slightly different than PHP’s
  output, because this includes periods to match Associated Press
  style.)  'a.m.'
- T:Time zone of this machine. 'EST', 'MDT'

you can see more about date template on here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date